# Counting days, add comment every 5th row in a MySQL loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, date

I'm looping various dates from a MySQL table. But not more then one year back from today.
I want to count days between days. So if its more then 5 days between dates, I want to fill in a text.
I dont want to mark every 5th row! I want to put a mark when more then 5 days has passed between two dates in loop.
Like this:

```
2018-01-02
2018-01-01
New period
2017-12-15
2017-12-14
2017-12-11
2017-12-08
New period
2017-12-02
New period
2017-11-16
```

.

```
//Fetch dates

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM d_days WHERE `f_code` = 4 AND MAX A YEAR AGO ORDER BY ID DESC";

    $result = $db->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // Count total days
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    printf("You have total %d dates.\n", $row_cnt);

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 

{

if more than 5 days {    ////   ?????
echo "New period";
}

echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row['d_day'];
echo "</td></tr>";

        }

    } else {

        echo "Did not find any dates";

    }

    $result->close();
```

I dont know how to count the dates. Datediff? How do I fetch dates in a loop?

d_day is datetime  0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: There is more then 5 days between `2017-12-15` and `2017-12-08`.

Comment: It's not five days. It's five items. Maybe you can have a counter inside the loop somehow....

Comment: Use modulus operator if you just want inbetween every 5 rows. https://3v4l.org/4as3Y

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Its not every 5th row. Its when number of days ecxeeds 5 days. If more then 5 days occur between two dates,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can save the date value from the current row, and when processing the next row, we can calculate the number of days between the dates.

With PHP 5.3 and later, we can use the `diff` method of `DateTime` class to return a `DateInterval` class. And then use the `days` <strike>method</strike> property to get the number of whole days.

Something like this:

```
    $d1 = new DateTime();

    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() )  {
       // convert MySQL date string to a DateTime object
       $d2 = new DateTime( $row['d_day'] );

       // calculate number of whole days between 
       $numdays = $d1->diff($d2)->days;

       if( $numdays > 5 )  {
          echo "New period";
       }

       // ... whatever else we need to do with the row 

       // before we start the next iteration of the loop
       // save the date from this row so we can compare it to the next row
       $d1 = $d2;
    }
```

Comment: $numdays = $d1->diff($d2)->days();
Gives error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateInterval::days() in

Comment: `days` is a property, not a method. *DOH!* remove the extraneous (erroneous) parens. It should have been written `->days;`  not `->days();` My bad. I'll correct the code in the answer.  I don't have an explanation why the DateInterval class doesn't provide a `days()` method, and gives us a property. Whatever.

Comment: Thank you spencer7593! I have been fighting with this all weekend. Sorry for just pasting a simple code, but I hoped everyone should easier understand what I was need in help with.